# Modifying JSX script to save all images in folder as transparent PNG-24?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

So the below script simply loops through a chosen folder, checks canvas size and dimensions and sets them if they're not in a 1:1 aspect ratio, and if they are, leaves them alone. The result is all images in the folder saved in 1:1 aspect ratio at dimension of 1000 x 1000 px.

The problem is they're all saved as .JPG whereas I would prefer to save them as transparent PNG-24.

I assume somewhere in the `doc.save()` method there is a parameter for different file types? I cannot find any documentation on this and was wondering if someone more knowledgeable knew? Thank you!

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process"),
      fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|tif|psd|crw|cr2|nef|dcr|dc2|raw)$/i);

for(var i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var doc = open(fileList[i]);
    if(doc.width !== doc.height) {
        if(doc.width > doc.height) {
            doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)
        } else {
            doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)
        }
    }
    if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000) {
        doc.resizeImage(1000, 1000);
    } else {
        doc.resizeImage(doc.width, doc.height);
    }

    doc.save();
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right stack for this question I'm afraid! You can see what kind of questions are accepted here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I would possible try asking at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JacksonHyde You’re right that it’s more about programming question rather than graphics but there are plenty of Adobe scripts questions floating around here.

Comment: @JacksonHyde Question is ok. Just slightly too much  "do my work for me" like for my tastes.

Comment: @exception-io Googling "photoshop script save png" gives hundreds and thousands correct answers, I wonder what exactly hindered you from finding an answer: what did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: I agree with @Sergey Kritskiy that it should've very easy to find answer and You said no documents available then look at [this](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the modified code**

As per another answer, All you had to do was using "Save For Web" instead of save.

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to process"),
      fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(/\.(jpg|tif|psd|crw|cr2|nef|dcr|dc2|raw)$/i);

for(var i=0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var doc = open(fileList[i]);
    if(doc.width !== doc.height) {
        if(doc.width > doc.height) {
            doc.resizeCanvas(doc.width, doc.width)
        } else {
            doc.resizeCanvas(doc.height, doc.height)
        }
    }
    if((doc.width && doc.height) > 1000) {
        doc.resizeImage(1000, 1000);
    } else {
        doc.resizeImage(doc.width, doc.height);
    }
    var fpath = fileList[i].path;
    var saveFile = new File (fpath);
    var pngSaveOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    pngSaveOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    pngSaveOptions.PNG8 = false;
    pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
    app.activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, pngSaveOptions);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’d need either ‘Save As’ Or ‘Save for Web’ with options parameters in your script.

[Here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Photoshop/Save-to-PNG-options/m-p/10596204#M261589) is a thread discussing same thing. I can only point you in right direction but can’t modify your code right now.